# GKE with custom vm's node pools isn't scaling down

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a new node pool with a custom vm type, `n2-custom-16-24576`, in Google Kubernetes Engine.

When we had a normal vm type, `n2-standard-16`, the nodes were autoscale correctly, and almost all nodes was consuming >90% of cpu or mem resources but after changing the vm type the node number will remain the same even if the consumed resources are at 60-70%, so a lot of waste

Any hints if i'm making something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Using resource to 60-70% is too high to scale down, it's generally when you use less than 40% (with default parameter). What are your autoscaler parameters?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks, but the node pool with standard vm's were a lot better ballanced in terms or assigned request resources, for eg. in first node pool for 8-9 `n2-standard-16` vm's, 16 cores, almost all vm's had requested ±15 and maybe one was with 7 or so, with custom vm type in second node pool,  there are 13 vm's and all of them request ~9-10 cpu ( memory is at 50% )

Comment: Could you share your configuration for scaling? Whats your n2-custom configuration (how many CPU, RAM, etc)? How long did you wait to downscale cluster nodes? Are you scaling only using CPU or also RAM?

Comment: @PjoterS `n2-custom-16-24576` means `n2` cpu with `16cpu's` and `24GB` ram. The cluster didn't scale down for days. And the "scaling only using CPU or also RAM" I think is managed by GKE. is there an option to set a threshold for this in Google Kubernetes Engine?

Comment: --autoscaling-profile optimize-utilization

Comment: I think this flag is the only option :) `--autoscaling-profile optimize-utilization`

Comment: It's autopilot or normal cluster? Cluster Autoscaler works on node pool basics. Do you have 2 node pools? 1 with `n2-standard-16` (16CPU, 64GB Ram, it worked as expected) but it's not scaling down when you are using `n2-custom-16-24576` (16CPU, 24GBRam). It was also an `optimize-utilization` profile? Are you using both node-pools? Can you see any specific logs regarding downscale in GCP Logs (Error, Warnings, Failures)? Did you set any Minimum/Maximum numbers of the nodes in the nodepool? How many nodes do you have at the moment? In both nodes pools you had the same pods?

Comment: You don't  have `PodDisruptionBudget` or `eviction rules`? According to [this docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-does-scale-down-work) this is intended behavior as `Cluster Autoscaler` downscale nodes when utilization is less in 50% and your nodes have about 60%/70% of the utilization. Is there any test you could perform to check if you would decrease load to less than 50% it will downscale?

Comment: @PjoterS good reference, thanks :) normal cluster, for `--autoscaling-profile` the possible values are `balance` ( default ) and `optimize-utilization` as per (this doc)[https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#autoscaling_profiles] and with the `optimized` profile works better ... but for some reason on previous node pool ( w. `cos` img type, idk if matters ) works good in `balanced` mode and when I changed to `cos_optimized` and `custom` vm type wasn't good, I mean it stays at >50% but 50% not used res. are pretty much :)

Comment: My best guess would be that node needs to have about >50%  utilization before scaling down. If this is not set [limit](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler?hl=en#autoscaling_limits) nor [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler?hl=en#limitations). Last thing I would check is to find `NoScaleDown` log via doc [Viewing cluster autoscaler events](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility?hl=en)

Comment: If this won't provide any idea I would suggest to create [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) for the google team.

Comment: hey @PjoterS setting `--autoscaling-profile  optimize-utilization` works good

Comment: So both node pools (`cos_optimized` and `custom`) work fine with `--autoscaling-profile  optimize-utilization` and node pool is scaling down when there is about 60% of the usage? If so, after changing profile to `optimize-utilization` it works as you expected?